# Default parameter value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

Can a report have a default parameter value without prompting for data? Such as making a report that automatically only pulls data from yesterday? From the last 7 work days, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Use calculations based on `CurrentDate`. To get yesterday's date, use `CurrentDate - 1`, or if you only want records from the last week, filer out any  records dated before `CurrentDate - 7`

This can either be implemented as an optional parameter (which defaults to yesterday if you leave it blank) or if you never want to prompt the user for input, skip the parameter entirely and place your formula directly into the record selection formula editor.

Comment: @CrystalN00b In regards to your latest question about the -7 +7, you'll want to change the equals sign to a `>=` sign. Thanks, and don't forget to accept an answer if it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do what 4444 said in the Select Expert:

```
{date_field} = CurrentDate - 1 //For yesterdays data

{date_field} = CurrentDate - 7 //For the last weeks data
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! As always, you guys come through in fine style. I'm shocked this was so difficult to find, but as always thank you!!!!

Comment: One last question in case someone is monitoring this thread, using the currentdate -7 or +7 should show ALL records within that range, not just 7 days ago or 7 days from now, correct? It doesn't appear to be working that way.